# How to search from two or more lists using list.js

Tags: javascript, list.js

I want to ask that how can I retrieve filtered results from two or more list using list.js

Let me explain using pictures:

[image]

Here's my HTML:

```
<div id="SearchBarContainer" class="col l10 offset-l1">
                        <input name="SearchData" class="search" placeholder="Search Anything !" />
                        <h1 class="McqHeading">MCQs</h1>
                        <ul class="list">
                            <li>
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs One</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Two</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Three</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Four</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Five</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                        <h1 class="NotesHeading">Notes</h1>
                        <ul class="list2">
                            <li>
                                <p class="note">Notes One</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="note">Notes Two</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="note">Notes Three</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="note">Notes Four</p>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <p class="note">Notes Five</p>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

Here's the Javascript I'm using for this:

```
var options = {
valueNames: [ 'mcq','note' ],
listClasses: ['list','list2']
};

 var DownloadsList = new List('SearchBarContainer', options);
```

Here's the result that it produces:

[image]

When I typed **b** it only checked in the First list. I want the code to check in both lists.

Is there any way to do so?

Comment: give  a common class in all the option and then in value name give that class and then try

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok. Your issue had solved.I use two different containers and two diferrent list objects as shown below:

```js
var options_1 = {
  valueNames: [ 'mcq' ]
};
    
var options_2 = {
  valueNames: [ 'note' ]
};

var list1 = new List("SearchBarContainer_1",options_1);
var list2 = new List("SearchBarContainer_2",options_2);

$(".search").keyup(function(){
    list1.search($(this).val());
    list2.search($(this).val());
});
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/list.js/1.5.0/list.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input name="SearchData" class="search" placeholder="Search Anything !" />
    <div id="SearchBarContainer_1" class="col l10 offset-l1">
                        
                        <h1 class="McqHeading">MCQs</h1>
                        <ul class="list">
                          
                            <li class="a">
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs One</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="a">
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Two</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="a">
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Three</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="a">
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Four</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="a">
                                <p class="mcq">Mcqs Five</p>
                            </li>
                            </ul>
                            </div>
    <div id="SearchBarContainer_2" class="col l10 offset-l1">   
                        <h1 class="NotesHeading">Notes</h1>
                       <ul class="list">
                            <li class="b">
                                <p class="note">Notes One</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="b">
                                <p class="note">Notes Two</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="b">
                                <p class="note">Notes Three</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="b">
                                <p class="note">Notes Four</p>
                            </li>
                            <li class="b">
                                <p class="note">Notes Five</p>
                            </li>
                         
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```